# $a + b = 2$ implies $a^c + b^c \ge 2$ for any real $c \ge 1$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, proof-writing, exponential-function, alternative-proof

If $a, b, c$ are positive reals such that $c \ge 1$ and $a + b \ge 2$ then $a^c + b^c \ge 2$. Is there any elementary way to prove it without using calculus and advanced inequalities like Jensen's?

Note: I know how to prove it with Jensen, I was just wondering if it can be done using simple, basic, elementary theorems and inequalities.

Comment: If you can prove it for rational $c$ you can use continuity to get it for real $c$. That might make it easier.

Comment: If $a=b=1$ then the inequality is satisfied otherwise take, WLOG $a=1+x$ and $b=1-x$ then by Bernoulli $a^c\geq 1+cx$ and $b^c\geq 1-cx$ and $a^c+b^c\geq 1+cx+1-cx=2$.(Similar to Michael's solution)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By Bernoulli $$a^c=(1+a-1)^c\geq1+c(a-1),$$
$$b^c\geq1+c(b-1).$$
Id est,
$$a^c+b^c\geq2+c(a+b-2)=2.$$

Comment: "without using calculus and advanced inequalities like Jensen's?"

Comment: @eyeballfrog I fixed. What do you think about Bernoulli?

Comment: That's fine, Bernoulli inequality has quite reasonable proof.

Answer (score 0):

Look at $f(x) = (1 + x)^c + (1 - x)^c$. We have $f(0) = 2$, and

$$f'(x) = c(1 + x)^{c-1} - c(1 - x)^{c-1}$$

Thus $f'(x) \geq 0$ if  $c \geq 1$ and $0 \leq x \leq 1$.

So for $0 \leq x \leq 1$ one has $f(x) \geq f(0) = 2$. Suppose
$a + b = 2$. WLOG we can assume $b \geq a$. Then we can let $x = {b - a \over 2}$ in which case $1 + x = b$ and $1 - x = a$, giving your result.

Yeah, I know it's calculus but I think this is a natural elementary way to do it.